# Building android for hammerhead - phone can't boot

Tags: android, operating-system, kernel

I've got a spare Nexus 5, and I've decided to play along and try to build android for it. However, when I try to boot what I've built, it shows only the 'Google Logo and open padlock' splashscren, and does nothing more.

My steps in building the whole android os:

Kernel:

I download msm kernel from git, then I check out remotes/origin/android-msm-hammerhead-3.4-marshmallow-mr1 branch, then I build the kernel in following way:

```
export PATH=/home/netaro/Android/AndroidSourceCode/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/bin/:$PATH

cd MSMKernel

export ARCH=arm
export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-androideabi-

make clean
make hammerhead_defconfig
make CONFIG_NO_ERROR_ON_MISMATCH=y CONFIG_FRAME_WARN=0
```

Then, I copy arch/arm/boot/Image and arch/arm/boot/zImage-dtb to where android source code lives, to device/lge/hammerhead-kernel directory.

Then, I build android by doing following steps ->

```
. ./build/envsetup.sh
make clean
lunch 19
#tried selecting kernel by this variable, but changes nothing, won't boot
#export TARGET_PREBUILT_KERNEL=/home/netaro/Android/MSMKernel/arch/arm/boot/zImage-dtb
make updatepackage -j4
```

After it all builds, I unzip out/target/product/hammerhead/aosp-hammerhead...zip package, boot the phone to fastboot, and fastboot flash each element:

```
fastboot flash boot boot.img
fastboot flash system.img
fastboot flash cache cache.img
fastboot flash recovery recovery.img
fastboot flash userdata userfata.img
```

Then, I select Start in bootloader, and it stops on the 'Google with open padlock' screen... Android source code is synced to a marshmallow source code via repo sync (I don't remember the name right now).

So, what am I doing wrong? Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, seem solved. It seems like qcom-hammerhead-... binaries from google's "Binaries for Nexus Devices" site are required to make it work. Download qcom-hammerhead-... from there, unpack to where source code lives, and rebuild.